# Can I create a man page for a script?

Tags: bash, man

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add man page entries for my own power tools?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/how-can-i-add-man-page-entries-for-my-own-power-tools)

Most (if not all) Linux commands have their man pages that describe their usage options etc. 
Can I create similar man page for my own bash scripts?

Comment: Apparently I miss-clicked downvote and now its set in stone, sorry about that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Man pages are roff (see `man 7 roff`) formatted documents.

- You can write it by hand.
- You can use [`help2man`](http://www.gnu.org/software/help2man/) to generate it from your script's help output.
- You can write it in a markup language and use a dedicated tool to convert it to man:

  - `a2x` (from the *asciidoc* package) for [AsciiDoc](http://methods.co.nz/asciidoc/)
  - `grutatxt` for [Grutatxt](http://triptico.com/software/grutatxt.html)
  - `pod2man` (from the *perl* package) for [POD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html)
  - `rst2man` (from the *docutils* package) for [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html)
  - `txt2tags` for [txt2tags](http://txt2tags.org/)
  - [Mantastic](http://mantastic.herokuapp.com/) (a Heroku web service) for [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)

Comment: There is also Ronn: https://rtomayko.github.io/ronn/

Comment: Give a try [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) (see my [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375035/28115) to learn more).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. The man pages are written as [nroff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nroff) files.
The /usr/local/man directory is the location typically used for any locally installed packages/files.
You can look at examples by looking at the existing manpages, (which will likely need to be uncompressed first), also read [man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).
Presently many users prefer groff to nroff, `man groff` to get started