# Nested lists in man page

Tags: man, roff

I have a command line parameter that takes a number of flags afterwards, which I would like to have as a list inside the parameter list in the man page.

Currently I am simply making lines of `Flag - Description` ([man page](http://paste.ubuntu.com/968689/)), but this is not ideal for the following reasons:

- Doesn't indent wrapped lines. I can manually indent them but then I have to assume a set console width, which I don't want to do
- Have to rely on double newlines to go to the next line, I'd rather have something like `.TP`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Start the list with `.RS`, end with `.RE`.
- Start list items with `.IP` followed by term. Enclose the term in double quotes if contains multiple words.
- Put the description text in the next line after the list item start.
- Is nestable, so the description may contain further lists.
- Use `\fB`..`\fP` for bolding the term instead of `.B`. (Same for underline – use `\fI`..`\fP` instead of `.I`.)

```
.RS
.IP \fBA\fP
\- Flag 1
.IP \fBB\fP
\- Flag 2
.IP \fBC\fP
\- A slightly longer flag description that could take up more than the width
of the average console. In fact you'd need a very wide console to read all
this.
.RE
```

To increase your productivity I suggest to write your man pages in a friendlier format then convert them. Some suitable tools are enumerated in [Can I create a man page for a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34516/can-i-create-a-man-page-for-a-script).