# How to create Info documentation?

Tags: documentation, info

[How can I add man page entries for my own power tools?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/how-can-i-add-man-page-entries-for-my-own-power-tools) got me thinking: How would one create an Info page?

Comment: `info info` then `Expert info` tells you...

Comment: @geedoubleya `info info` refers me to `info texinfo` but i can't install `texinfo` on this offline test machine i'm using. What's `Expert`?

Comment: "Expert info" is a chapter that provides how to create info documents. - Should have surrounded it in quotes rather than backticks...

Comment: [I see.](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info/html_node/Expert-Info.html#Expert-Info) Must be past of the `texinfo` info.

Comment: Indeed - online version on [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info/info.html#Expert-Info)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create Info documentation, you first need a texi file.

`.texi` - [Texinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo) is a typesetting syntax used for generating documentation in both on-line and printed form (creating filetypes as dvi, html, pdf, etc., and its own hypertext format, info) with a single source file. It is implemented by a computer program released as free software of the same name, created and made available by the GNU Project from the Free Software Foundation.

`.info` - Info (Generated via `makeinfo`.) This is a specific format which essentially is a plain text version of the original Texinfo syntax in conjunction with a few control characters to separate nodes and provide navigational elements for menus, cross-references, sections, and so on. The Info format can be viewed with the `info` program.

`makeinfo` is a utility that converts a Texinfo file into an Info file; [it is part of the texinfo package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338317/what-is-makeinfo-and-how-do-i-get-it). `texinfo-format-region` and `texinfo-format-buffer` are GNU Emacs functions that do the same.

Here is [a texi sample to use as a template](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/GNU-Sample-Texts.html):

```
\input texinfo   @c -*-texinfo-*-
@comment $Id@w{$}
@comment %**start of header
@setfilename sample.info
@include version.texi
@settitle GNU Sample @value{VERSION}
@syncodeindex pg cp
@comment %**end of header
@copying
This manual is for GNU Sample (version @value{VERSION}, @value{UPDATED}),
which is an example in the Texinfo documentation.

Copyright @copyright{} 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

@quotation
Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this document
under the terms of the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.3 or
any later version published by the Free Software Foundation; with no
Invariant Sections, with no Front-Cover Texts, and with no Back-Cover
Texts.  A copy of the license is included in the section entitled
``GNU Free Documentation License''.
@end quotation
@end copying

@dircategory Texinfo documentation system
@direntry
* sample: (sample)Invoking sample.
@end direntry

@titlepage
@title GNU Sample
@subtitle for version @value{VERSION}, @value{UPDATED}
@author A.U. Thor (@email{bug-sample@@gnu.org})
@page
@vskip 0pt plus 1filll
@insertcopying
@end titlepage

@contents

@ifnottex
@node Top
@top GNU Sample

This manual is for GNU Sample (version @value{VERSION}, @value{UPDATED}).
@end ifnottex

@menu
* Invoking sample::
* GNU Free Documentation License::
* Index::
@end menu


@node Invoking sample
@chapter Invoking sample

@pindex sample
@cindex invoking @command{sample}

This is a sample manual.  There is no sample program to
invoke, but if there were, you could see its basic usage
and command line options here.


@node GNU Free Documentation License
@appendix GNU Free Documentation License

@include fdl.texi


@node Index
@unnumbered Index

@printindex cp

@bye
```

[Convert that into Info documentation](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/texinfo/texinfo_21.html) with:

```
makeinfo mytool.texi
```

[**Listing a New Info File**](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/texinfo/texinfo_22.html#SEC201)

To add a new Info file to your system, write a menu entry for it in the menu in the `dir` file in the `info` directory (`/usr/share/info/` on Ubuntu). Also, move the new Info file itself to the `info` directory. For example, if you were adding documentation for GDB, you would write the following new entry:

```
* GDB: (gdb).           The source-level C debugger.
```

The first part of the menu entry is the menu entry name, followed by a colon. The second part is the name of the Info file, in parentheses, followed by a period. The third part is the description.

Conventionally, the name of an Info file has a `.info` extension. Thus, you might list the name of the file like this:

```
* GDB: (gdb.info).           The source-level C debugger.
```

However, Info will look for a file with a `.info` extension if it does not find the file under the name given in the menu. This means that you can refer to the file `gdb.info` as `gdb`, as shown in the first example. This looks better.