# Creating .info files to be used with tree

Tags: tree, info

`man tree`<sup>1</sup> states:

> `-info` Prints file comments found in .info files.  See .INFO FILES below for more information on the format of .info files.

and further

> **.INFO FILES**
>
> .info files are similiar to .gitignore files, if a .info file is found while scanning a directory it is read and added to a stack of .info information. Each file is composed of comments (lines starting with hash marks (#),) or wild-card
> patterns which may match a file relative to the directory the .info file is found in.  If a file should match a pattern, the tab indented comment that follows the pattern is used as the file comment.  A comment is terminated by a non-tab
> indented line. Multiple patterns, each to a line, may share the same comment.

## Objective

Given the following directory structure:

```
tree

    .
    ├── fileA.txt
    ├── fileB.txt
    └── other_files
        └── fileC.txt
```

I would like to create a an info file(s) that would enable me to get the following output

```
    .
    ├── fileA.txt      # Comments on file A read from info file
    ├── fileB.txt      # Comments on file B read from info file
    └── other_files
        └── fileC.txt
```

Following the `man` pages this should be possible but I can't find an example how such an info file should be created. <strike>I've identified [one potentially relevant discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164443/159721)</strike><sup>2</sup> but it's not clear to me what should be the structure of this `.info` file so `tree` can use it to populate outputs with additional comments.

---

<sup>1</sup>Version: tree v2.0.2 (c) 1996 - 2022 by Steve Baker, Thomas Moore, Francesc Rocher, Florian Sesser, Kyosuke Tokoro*

<sup>2</sup> As discussed in the comments, the link is not pertinent to this question.

Comment: The *one potentially relevant discussion* is not relevant, it's about files with the `.info` extension which contain markup language for the `info` command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I had a hunch that this may be the case; hence *potentially*. I will highlight this in the question.

Comment: You can find an extended example at https://fossies.org/linux/tree/doc/global_info. But what I'm more interested in is: is this `.info` file just an oddity of `tree` or are there other tools supporting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
$ cat .info
a.jpg
        blah blah
        blih blih
*.jpg
        jpeg picture
$ tree --info
.
├── a.jpg
│    ⎧ blah blah
│    ⎩ blih blih
├── a.png
├── b.jpg
│    { jpeg picture
├── b.png
└── foo.user

0 directories, 5 files
```

(with a TAB preceding the comments per the manual you quoted).